# Using divide difference formula find the value of $f\left[x_{0},x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{10}\right]$

Tags: numerical-methods

Consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^{10}+x-1$ , $x\in \mathbb R$ & let $x_{k}=k$ for $k=0,1,2,...,10$. Then the value of the divide difference $f\left[x_{0},x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{10}\right]=$

(a) $-1$

(b) $0$

(c) $1$

(d) $10$.

From definition of Divide difference formula I can compute it, but it is too large & very laborious.

I want any short method or any trick to find the value very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember Newton's divided difference gives you the interpolating polynomial

$$f[x_0]+f[x_0,x_1](x-x_0)+f[x_0,x_1,x_2](x-x_0,x-x_1)+...+f[x_0,x_1,...,x_{10}](x-x_0)...(x-x_9)$$

This is a polynomial with degree $10$. It is exactly the original $f(x)$, and $f[x_0,x_1,...,x_10]$ should just be the coefficient of $x^{10}$, which is $1$.